# Twitter typeahead.js save remote response into localStorage

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js

I was wondering if there is a posibility to save remote queries into localSorage with typeahead.js.

I had this working with Bootstrap 2 typeahead but cant figure out with typeahead.js.

Example:
In input i type: "Ger"

The script checks if there is something in localStorage.

- If **NOT** get response from remote url and save it in localStorage.
- If **YES** get data from localStorage and print it.

I am using [typeahead.js 0.9.3](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/)

Answer (score 1):

There *is* such a possibility, for `prefetch` data. From the docs:

> Prefetched data is fetched and processed on initialization. If the
>   browser supports localStorage, the processed data will be cached there
>   to prevent additional network requests on subsequent page loads.

... and the relevant option in the `prefetch` object is:

> `ttl` – The time (in milliseconds) the prefetched data should be cached in localStorage. > Defaults to 86400000 (1 day).

See here: https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js#prefetch

From looking at the source, it further appears that:

1. PersistentStorage is indeed only for `prefetch`, and to be used the dataset must be initialized with a `name`.
2. There is an additional, in-memory, request/response cache in the Transport layer.